# How can I AUTOMATICALLY forward Facebook messages to my email?

Tags: facebook

I am *told* that I can **AUTOMATICALLY** (not manually) forward my Facebook messages to my email account but I can't find how to do that in the Facebook settings.

1) Can Facebook messages be **automatically** forwarded?
2) How do I do that?

(YES someone asked this very same question but the answers were to the question  "How can I *manually* forward messages." so I'm asking again.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [If This Then That(or IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/)?

You would need to open an account, and create channels both for your Facebook account and for your email account. When that is set up, you'll want to create a recipe that forwards your facebook messages (THIS) to your email address (THAT).

Another service you might want to look at is [Zapier](http://www.zapier.com), which works in a similar fashion.

I hope that helps.

Comment: just tried using these services - they did not offer such feature.

Comment: Specifically, IFTTT allows you forward posts BY you but not TO you. By "my messages" I meant messages TO me.

Comment: IFTTT allows you to forward Facebook Messenger posts by you?